# Binding with regex does not trigger on model update

Tags: javascript, regex, sapui5

I have a sap.m.Input with a regex binding. When my input is "A", "B" or "C" my text is black, otherwise it becomes red through CSS.

```
oComponent.attachValidationError(function(oEvent) {
  oEvent.getParameter("element").addStyleClass("become-red");
});
oComponent.attachValidationSuccess(function(oEvent) {
  oEvent.getParameter("element").removeStyleClass("become-red");
});

var oInput = new sap.m.Input( {
      value: {
        path: "Qux>/foo/0/bar/0/baz",
        type: new sap.ui.model.type.String(null, {
          search: new RegExp("^[ABC]$")
        })
    }
    });
```

When the value is "A" and I change it to "B", this works properly.

Then, if I do

```
oModelQux.setProperty("/foo/0/bar", [{
"baz" : "A"}]);
```

This works properly, the value becomes "A" again. My problem is that when I change the value of the input to a value which is not alllowed (e.g. "D"), and then I try my code

```
oModelQux.setProperty("/foo/0/bar", [{
"baz" : "A"}]);
```

nothing happens. The input does automatically update to "A", it just leaves the string "D" in red.

Comment: Why do you call setProperty on your model after entering the value in the input field?

Comment: @matbtt This is for a registration system where it is possible to enter a value (e.g. 'A' for Absent). Each line has an undo button, which uses setProperty to refresh the relevant data. If someone types an invalid value, and subsequently wants to undo the actions for that aggregation ('/foo/0/bar'), I send an AJAX request to get the current valid values for '/foo/0/bar'. Then I use the setProperty to attempt to get my userinterface to update the relevant fields.

Answer (score 2):

The binding should avoid that wrong values are stored in the model. If you change the value from "A" to "D" the value is never stored in the model, i.e. the model holds still "A". Thus your call to setProperty has no effect, as the internal value of the binding has never changed and setProperty does not force bindings to update in case of unchanged data.
I suggest that you obtain the binding of the input field if the button is clicked and call refresh(true). This should work (not tested).

Beside that I would suggest to use a Select control as it looks like that the available values are fixed. This would make the special logic obsolete.

Comment: Based on your answer I checked **oModel.updateBindings(true)**, which works. However, the screen contains hundreds to possibly thousands of inputs, through which end users will press 'tab' in order to fill them out quickly. Hence, a **sap.m.Select** control would be of no use in this scenario, and **oModel.updateBindings(true)** adds 5 seconds to evvery 'undo' action. In order to only refresh the specific input, I would first have to custom-build a system which keeps track of **sap.m.Input** fields that fail the regex check. I will give you +1 for a correct analysis and partial solution

Comment: Okay. As mentioned you can obtain the binding of the Input and refresh that specific binding.

Comment: I used your suggestion to answer the question, but I still had to add some code. Works well now, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Based on matbtt's answer, the following solution works without sacrifing performance:

undo for a single entry ('foo' level) triggers the following event:

```
  oEventBus.publish("undo", "undoAll", oContext.getPath());
```

undo for all lines triggers the following event:

```
  oEventBus.publish("undo", "undoAll");
```

attaching the following change function to each input:

```
var oInput = new sap.m.Input( {
      value: {
        path: "Qux>/foo/0/bar/0/baz",
        type: new sap.ui.model.type.String(null, {
          search: new RegExp("^[ABC]$")
        }),
       change: function(oEvent){
            var that = this;
            var oRegex = new RegExp("^[ABC]$");
            var bTest = oRegex.test(oEvent.getParameters().newValue);
            if (!bTest) {
              var fnSubscribe = function(sChannelId, sEventId, oData) {
                if (!oData || oData === oContext.getPath()) {
                  that.mBindingInfos.value.binding.refresh(true);
                  that.removeStyleClass("invalid-value");
                  oComponent.getEventBus().unsubscribe("undo", "undoAll", fnSubscribe);
                }
              };
             oComponent.getEventBus().subscribe("undo", "undoAll", fnSubscribe);
            }
         }
       }
    });
```